# C into shell code

Tags: c, shellcode

I'm trying to get a shellcode using C. I cannot just take `.obj` file due to the large amount of nulls. I've also tried "Shellcode Compiler", but it hasn't helped me.

Are there any other projects which can help me, or any ways to create a useable shell code from C?
My simple C code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    WinExec("SomeFile", 0);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for C shellcode samples? And the code you posted is what you want to inject the payload into?

Comment: I'm looking for projects which can convert simple C codes into Shell

Comment: A few things: 1. What shellcode compiler did you try and in what way didn't it work? 2. Are you familiar with _The Shellcoder's Handbook_? 3. Have you considered, rather than invoking this function, calling `ShellExecute`, `CreateProcessW`, `CreateProcessA`, `NTCreateProcess`, the `...Ex` versions of any of those, or even directly invoking the `NTCreateProcess`/`NtCreateUserProcess` system call? Also consider the `LoadLibrary` variants. Any of those might have e.g. friendlier addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that c is a compiled language and not interpreted. I am sure you will get better results from converting the binary to shellcode.

Check out GitHub [vulnwarex/bin2sc](https://github.com/vulnwarex/bin2sc).

Comment: The vast majority of the c to shell projects out there simply compile the c, then spit out shellcode derived from an objdump on the resulting binary. In many cases it is far better to get to grips with your compiler chain of choice, optimise the output and then go through the motions of producing viable shellcode.